# Api JSON Decode Reply

Tags: php, json, guzzle

im trying to receive an reply from the api as per below command

```
$client=new \GuzzleHttp\Client();
                $response=$client->request(
                    'post',
                    'https://cowpay.me/api/v0/fawry/charge-request-cc',
                    [
                    'json' =>[
                        'merchant_code' => $merchant_code,
                        'merchant_reference_id' => $merchant_reference_id,
                        'signature' => hash('sha256',$merchant_code.$merchant_reference_id.$user_id.$payment_method.$item_amout_fix.$m_hash_key),
                        'customer_name'=>$user_name,
                        'customer_email'=>$customer_email,
                        'customer_mobile'=>  $customer_mobile,
                        'customer_merchant_profile_id' => $user->id,
                        'currency_code' =>'EGP',
                        'amount' => $item_amout_fix,
                        'payment_method'=>'CARD',
                        'description' => $description,
                        'charge_items'=> [
                            'itemId'=> $item_number,
                            'description'=> $description,
                            'price'=> $item_amout_fix,
                            'quantity'=> '1',
                            ],
                            'card_number' => $request->card,
                            'expiry_year' => $request->year,
                            'expiry_month' => $request->month,
                            'cvv' => $request->cvv,
                            'save_card'     => '0',
                            ]
                            ] );
$response=json_decode($response->getBody()->getContents(), true);
return $response;
```

how ever this used to work and get the response in the form of 
https://prnt.sc/s4xcra

but now i get server error and laravel logs shows the message clearly with a clear and correct status code but wont get it back to the front end

```
local.ERROR: Client error: `POST https://cowpay.me/api/v0/fawry/charge-request-cc` resulted in a `422 Unprocessable Entity` response:
{"success":false,"message":"The given data was invalid.","status_code":422,"status_description":"The given data was inva (truncated...)
```

to be noted the code is totally correct as i send a valid data and it gives me another status code but in laravel> storage > logs >

Comment: You shouldn't test production before you are aware that development works fine (i.e. http://staging.cowpay.me/api/v0/fawry/charge-request-cc link).

Answer (score 0):

Check [the CowPay API docs](https://cowpay.me/docs/api/pay-using-cash-at-fawry). The 422 status code is a response from CowPay telling you that the data you're sending them is invalid.

At a guess, it's because you haven't correctly set the headers and body of your request. Your JSON should be in the body of the request, and encoded as such with `json_encode`. Your headers should also list the `Content-Type` of your request.

Try changing the arguments of your request to the following:

```
 'post',
 'https://cowpay.me/api/v0/fawry/charge-request-cc',
 [
     "headers" => [
         "Accept" => "application/json",
         "Content-Type" => "application/json"
     ],
     "body" => json_encode([
         'merchant_code' => $merchant_code,
         'merchant_reference_id' => $merchant_reference_id,
         'signature' => hash('sha256',$merchant_code.$merchant_reference_id.$user_id.$payment_method.$item_amout_fix.$m_hash_key),
         'customer_name'=>$user_name,
         'customer_email'=>$customer_email,
         'customer_mobile'=>  $customer_mobile,
         'customer_merchant_profile_id' => $user->id,
         'currency_code' =>'EGP',
         'amount' => $item_amout_fix,
         'payment_method'=>'CARD',
         'description' => $description,
         'charge_items'=> [
             'itemId'=> $item_number,
             'description'=> $description,
             'price'=> $item_amout_fix,
             'quantity'=> '1',
         ],
         'card_number' => $request->card,
         'expiry_year' => $request->year,
         'expiry_month' => $request->month,
         'cvv' => $request->cvv,
         'save_card'     => '0',
     ])
 ]
```

Comment: this is diffidently not fixing it , i still got an replies like
local.ERROR: Client error: `POST https://cowpay.me/api/v0/fawry/charge-request-cc` resulted in a `422 Unprocessable Entity` response:
{"success":false,"message":"The given data was invalid.","status_code":422,"status_description":"The given data was inva (truncated...)

Comment: also for your infromation it returns into the error codes another codes like 4050, 200 but it never show them on screen it gives me interal error and i have to check them in logs

Comment: [4050](https://cowpay.me/docs/api/codes) is somewhat good™ code.

Comment: yeah but in error it used to be catched as array now it comming to logs only, which mean it causes error and catched by expection of try and catch so i cant use it for no reason

Comment: @Tpojka Only slightly less concerning than your payment processing system returning a 418 :D